# What is the difference between importing the Fernet object and importing the full module?

Tags: python

I have a question about the differences between same things but one is I'm importing directly, and the other I'm just importing the full module.

The output between them is need to be the same, it is need to generate a key, but on the first example I'm getting an error `module 'cryptography' has no attribute 'fernet'`, and I wonder why ?

**First Example:**

```
import cryptography

key = cryptography.fernet.Fernet.generate_key()
print(key)
```

**Second Example:**

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = Fernet.generate_key()
print(key)
```

What is the different between them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `import module` in python imports what is available in `module/__init__.py` file [*]. If `module/` directory has `submodule/` subdirectory, it doesn't mean that `import module` will know anything about `module.submodule`.

Try a simple experiment.

Create the following directories and files:

```
module/
├── __init__.py
└── submodule
    └── __init__.py
```

Now put this code into `module/__init__.py`:

```
X = 1
```

and this code into `module/submodule/__init__.py`

```
Y = 2
```

Now in Python:

```
>>> import module
>>> module.X
1
>>> module.submodule.Y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'module' has no attribute 'submodule'
>>> import module.submodule
>>> module.submodule.Y
2
>>>
```

As you can see, `import module` does not bring in `module.submodule`. Now modify `module/__init__.py` so that it reads

```
import module.submodule
X = 1
```

Now submodule is visible inside `module/__init__.py` and will be brought in on import. Restart Python, and:

```
>>> import module
>>> module.submodule.Y
2
```

[*] I'm lying here. The rules are a bit more obscure, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import (search there for `__all__`) but my simplification is good for the first explanation.